# Change color to kelvin

Tags: javascript, react-native

I come to you because I have a problem with this library react-native-color-wheel, I would like to change the wheel so that it becomes a wheel of colors in kelvin. I've tried to tinker with several things but without any effect, I'm really struggling with polar calculations and all that goes with it if someone could point me to it.

Thanks to you guys

```js
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Animated, Image, Dimensions, PanResponder, View } from 'react-native';
import colorsys from 'colorsys';

import styles from './styles';

export default class ColorWheelWhite extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor: PropTypes.number,
    initialColor: PropTypes.string,
    onColorChangeComplete: PropTypes.func,
    thumbSize: PropTypes.number,
    onColorChange: PropTypes.func,
    thumbStyle: PropTypes.object,
    prevState: PropTypes.string,
    style: PropTypes.object
  };

  static defaultProps = {
    thumbSize: 50,
    initialColor: '#ffffff',
    onColorChange: () => {}
  };

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    const { toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor } = props;
    if (toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor !== state.toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor) {
      return {
        toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor
      };
    }
    return null;
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { initialColor, toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor = 0 } = props;
    this.state = {
      offset: { x: 100, y: 100 },
      currentColor: initialColor,
      pan: new Animated.ValueXY(),
      toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor,
      radius: 200,
      panHandlerReady: true,
      didUpdateThumb: false
    };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
      onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onStartShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      onPanResponderGrant: ({ nativeEvent }) => {
        if (this.outBounds(nativeEvent)) return;
        if (!this.state.didUpdateThumb) {
          this.updateColorAndThumbPosition(nativeEvent);
        }
      },
      onPanResponderMove: (event, gestureState) => {
        if (this.outBounds(gestureState)) return;

        if (!this.state.didUpdateThumb) {
          const { nativeEvent } = event;
          this.updateColorAndThumbPosition(nativeEvent);
        }

        this.resetPanHandler();
        return Animated.event(
          [
            null,
            {
              dx: this.state.pan.x,
              dy: this.state.pan.y
            }
          ],
          { listener: this.updateColor }
        )(event, gestureState);
      },
      onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: () => true,
      onPanResponderRelease: ({ nativeEvent }) => {
        this.setState({
          panHandlerReady: true,
          didUpdateThumb: false
        });
        this.state.pan.flattenOffset();
        const { radius } = this.calcPolar(nativeEvent);
        if (radius < 0.1) {
          this.forceUpdate('#ffffff');
        }

        if (this.props.onColorChangeComplete) {
          this.props.onColorChangeComplete(this.state.hsv);
        }
      }
    });
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    const { initialColor } = this.props;

    if (initialColor && this.state.toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor !== prevState.toggleMeToforceUpdateInitialColor) {
      this.forceUpdate(initialColor);
    }
  }

  updateColorAndThumbPosition(nativeEvent) {
    this.updateColor({ nativeEvent });

    this.state.pan.setValue({
      x: -this.state.left + nativeEvent.pageX - this.props.thumbSize / 2,
      y: -this.state.top + nativeEvent.pageY - this.props.thumbSize / 2
    });
    this.setState({
      didUpdateThumb: true
    });
  }

  onLayout = () => {
    this.measureOffset();
  };

  measureOffset() {
    /*
     * const {x, y, width, height} = nativeEvent.layout
     * onlayout values are different than measureInWindow
     * x and y are the distances to its previous element
     * but in measureInWindow they are relative to the window
     */
    this.self.measureInWindow((x, y, width, height) => {
      const window = Dimensions.get('window');
      const absX = x % width;
      const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
      const offset = {
        x: absX + width / 2,
        y: (y % window.height) + height / 2
      };

      this.setState({
        offset,
        radius,
        height,
        width,
        top: y % window.height,
        left: absX
      });
      this.forceUpdate(this.state.currentColor);
    });
  }

  calcPolar(gestureState) {
    const { pageX, pageY, moveX, moveY } = gestureState;
    const [x, y] = [pageX || moveX, pageY || moveY];
    const [dx, dy] = [x - this.state.offset.x, y - this.state.offset.y];
    return {
      deg: Math.atan2(dy, dx) * (-180 / Math.PI),
      // pitagoras r^2 = x^2 + y^2 normalized
      radius: Math.sqrt(dy * dy + dx * dx) / this.state.radius
    };
  }

  outBounds(gestureState) {
    const { radius } = this.calcPolar(gestureState);
    return radius > 1;
  }

  resetPanHandler() {
    if (!this.state.panHandlerReady) {
      return;
    }

    this.setState({ panHandlerReady: false });
    this.state.pan.setOffset({
      x: this.state.pan.x._value,
      y: this.state.pan.y._value
    });
    this.state.pan.setValue({ x: 0, y: 0 });
  }

  calcCartesian(deg, radius) {
    const r = radius * this.state.radius; // was normalized
    const rad = (Math.PI * deg) / 180;
    const x = r * Math.cos(rad);
    const y = r * Math.sin(rad);
    return {
      left: this.state.width / 2 + x,
      top: this.state.height / 2 - y
    };
  }

  updateColor = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { deg, radius } = this.calcPolar(nativeEvent);
    console.log("deg");
    console.log(deg);
    console.log("radius");
    console.log(radius);
    const hsv = { h: deg, s: 10 * radius, v: 100 };
    const currentColor = colorsys.hsv2Hex(hsv);
    this.setState({ hsv, currentColor });
    console.log("LE HSV");
    console.log(this.state.hsv);
    this.props.onColorChange(hsv);
  };

  forceUpdate = color => {
    const { h, s, v } = colorsys.hex2Hsv(color);
    const { left, top } = this.calcCartesian(h, s / 100);
    this.setState({ currentColor: color });
    this.props.onColorChange({ h, s, v });
    this.state.pan.setValue({
      x: left - this.props.thumbSize / 2,
      y: top - this.props.thumbSize / 2
    });
  };

  animatedUpdate = color => {
    const { h, s, v } = colorsys.hex2Hsv(color);
    const { left, top } = this.calcCartesian(h, s / 100);
    this.setState({ currentColor: color });
    this.props.onColorChange({ h, s, v });
    Animated.spring(this.state.pan, {
      toValue: {
        x: left - this.props.thumbSize / 2,
        y: top - this.props.thumbSize / 2
      }
    }).start();
  };

  setRef = ref => {
    this.self = ref;
  };

  render() {
    const { radius } = this.state;
    const thumbStyle = [
      styles().circle,
      this.props.thumbStyle,
      {
        width: this.props.thumbSize,
        height: this.props.thumbSize,
        borderRadius: this.props.thumbSize / 2,
        backgroundColor: this.state.currentColor,
        opacity: this.state.offset.x === 0 ? 0 : 1
      }
    ];

    const panHandlers = (this._panResponder && this._panResponder.panHandlers) || {};

    return (
      <View ref={this.setRef} onLayout={this.onLayout} style={[styles().coverResponder, this.props.style]} pointerEvents={'box-none'}>
        <Image
          style={[
            styles().img,
            {
              height: radius * 2,
              width: radius * 2,
              borderRadius: radius - this.props.thumbSize
            }
          ]}
          source={require('../../assets/color-wheel-white.png')}
          {...panHandlers}
        />
        <Animated.View style={[this.state.pan.getLayout(), thumbStyle]} pointerEvents={'box-none'} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you want to get more help, make it easier for others to help you: Try creating a runnable example (with codesandbox for example). Or just make your code minimalistic. Doing this will help you get answers.